# Share menu to save and share

Tags: android, android-menu

[image]I have a bitmap image in a view flipper and I need to show the share menu in Action bar.
Once I click on share icon, should open up a share options and save to Gallery.
Topic - Share and Save
Options - Save to Gallery, and default share options like GMAIL, Hangouts, etc.

I was able to create the menu:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.history_menu, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
        return true;
    }
```

I am able to get the Bitmap image from flipper:

```
  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_item_share:
                ImageView image = (ImageView) flipper.getCurrentView();
                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                /*Need to know how to share and save image*/

                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
```

I need to know whether we have any default Android share and save layout, which will show the above options, or do I have to create a custom layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
        // Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
                view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        // Bind a canvas to it
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        // Get the view's background
        Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable != null)
            // has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        else
            // does not have background drawable, then draw white background on
            // the canvas
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        // draw the view on the canvas
        view.draw(canvas);
        // return the bitmap
        return returnedBitmap;
    }

    private String SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/test");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-" + n + ".png";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

And for sharing

```
                        Bitmap b = getBitmapFromView(root);
                        String s = SaveImage(b);
                        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(
                                Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(s);
                        sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
                        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                                Uri.fromFile(new File(s)));
                        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                                "save to gallery");
                        startActivity(sharingIntent);
```

Comment: Can I store to an internal storage than storing in an external storage. Will the share options show "save to gallery" ?

Comment: I added the layout I need to show for Share.. I hope your answer would work. Let me implement and let you know. Also which one is better to save, internal or external?

Comment: I tried to send through gmail, but after I click send it says "Couldn't send attachment"

Comment: thats y i use external storage

Comment: I tried external storage, but to get the bitmap form View Flipper, I used  ImageView image = (ImageView) flipper.getCurrentView();
                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap(); but it fails, bluetooth says unknown file

Comment: Also Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(s); this piece of code is not being used